# Calculus Limit Calculation problem

Tags: calculus

The calculate the limit

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}+\frac{n}{n+2}+...+\frac{n}{2n}\right).$$

Answer options: (A) ∞ (B) 0 (C) ln 2 (D) 1

I can just cancel the $1/n$ with each term within the big series. So, would the answer be zero?

Comment: Who the hell approved this edit?

Comment: $0^+\times \infty \neq 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+r}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{1}^{n}\frac{1/n}{1+r/n}=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x}$$

Comment: and hence ln2.  I was scratching my head.  I could not guess it and I was trying squeeze theorem to come up with nothing with the original edit. Nice

Answer (score 0):

It is known that for $c_n=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n}-\ln n, \lim_{n \to \infty}c_n=c $.

$c$ is called Euler's constant.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}+\frac{n}{n+2}+...+\frac{n}{2n}\right)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n}\right)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+...+\frac{1}{2n}-\ln2n-(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n}-\ln n)+ \ln 2\right)=\lim_{n \to \infty}(c_{2n}-c_n+\ln 2)=\ln 2.$$